# Spark program behave differently based on --master is set to local[4] or yarn-client

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using the movielens dataset to load Movie information into a spark program and print the same using the following code snippet

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object MovieApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("movie-recommender")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)


    val movieFile = "/mnt/DATASETS/ml-1m/movies.dat"

    val movieData = sc.textFile(movieFile)

    val movies = movieData.map(_.split("::") match { case Array(movieid, title, genres) =>
      val genreList = genres.split("|")
      (movieid, title, genreList)
    })

    println("Num movies:" + movies.count())

    movies.foreach { case movielist =>
      println("ID:" + movielist._1 + "Title:" + movielist._2)
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the code using the command 
spark-submit --master local[4] --class "MovieApp" movie-recommender.jar I get the expected output as

*root@philli ml]# /usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --master local[4] --class "MovieApp" movie-recommender_2.10-1.0.jar

14/12/05 00:17:37 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Num movies:3883

ID:2020 Title:Dangerous Liaisons (1988)

ID:2021 Title:Dune (1984)

ID:2022 Title:Last Temptation of Christ, The (1988)

ID:2023 Title:Godfather: Part III, The (1990)

ID:2024 Title:Rapture, The (1991)

ID:2025 Title:Lolita (1997)

ID:2026 Title:Disturbing Behavior (1998)

ID:2027 Title:Mafia! (1998)

ID:2028 Title:Saving Private Ryan (1998)

ID:2029 Title:Billy's Hollywood Screen Kiss (1997)

...
*

but when I run the same on a hadoop cluster using the command

spark-submit --master yarn-client --class "MovieApp" movie-recommender.jar the output is different as below (no movie details???)

*[root@philli ml]# /usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-client  --class "MovieApp" movie-recommender_2.10-1.0.jar

14/12/05 00:21:05 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/12/05 00:21:07 WARN BlockReaderLocal: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
--args is deprecated. Use --arg instead.
Num movies:3883
[root@philli ml]# *

Why should the behavior of the program change between running it as local vs on the cluster....I have built spark-1.1.1 for hadoop using the command

> mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean
>   package

The cluster I am using is HDP2.1

Sample movies.dat file is as follows:

> 1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
>
> 2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
>
> 3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance
>
> 4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy|Drama
>
> 5::Father of the Bride Part II (1995)::Comedy
>
> 6::Heat (1995)::Action|Crime|Thriller
>
> 7::Sabrina (1995)::Comedy|Romance
>
> 8::Tom and Huck (1995)::Adventure|Children's
>
> 9::Sudden Death (1995)::Action
>
> 10::GoldenEye (1995)::Action|Adventure|Thriller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the program on a cluster, the `foreach` closure will be executed in the workers, therefore the `println` *is* happening, but on the worker's `stdout` and not on the driver.

Look into the yarn logs and you will find the expected output.

Comment: oh that makes sense...hmm so if I want the data in the driver then I will have to use take().